# 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered laravel on hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I can't access my site. '500 Internal Server Error error was encountered' this error occur when i try to access my root domain like mydomain.com

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you when you don't post what the error is.  Check your logs.

Comment: Check your apache logs for your site. It will reveal wonders.

Comment: my error log is empty. @Brad

Comment: This is the error...

'client denied by server configuration: /home/bdtimesc/public_html/.htaccess'

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None` in your apache config file. Is this a cpanel box?

Also try adding the rewritebase to the rules.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Like this below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where do you put this file? In public folder, like in Laravel setup, or is it in root folder of Laravel app?